# How to make an image so that objects reflect it?

Tags: rendering, image, reflection

fans!
I added an image as a plane into my environment (via the Import Images as Planes add-on). How can I change it so that an object reflects it in rendered mode? (an object e.g. reflects the background, but not the image)
[image: background-reflection works]
[image: image reflection doesn't work]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this (in 3.0, in Cycles) and in Rendered preview the image imported via File > Import > Images as Planes and the image imported via Add > Image > Images as Planes both show up fine in the surface of a reflective sphere:

[image]

Here's my test blendfile:

[image]

It's possible from the angle shown in your screenshot that the image is a little too far back to visibly reflect to the camera.